# Why don't I get the same output?

Tags: php, strstr

I am trying to check whether a string is PANGRAM but both the codes give different results.

**Number One -**

```
<?php
$line = strtolower(trim("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"));
$letters = str_split("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog");
$result = "pangram";

foreach ($letters as $value) {
    if (strstr($line, $value) == FALSE) {
        $result = "not pangram";
    }
}
echo $result;
?>
```

**Number Two -**

```
<?php
$line = strtolower(trim("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"));
$letters = str_split("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog");
$result = "not pangram";
foreach ($letters as $value) {
    if (strstr($line, $value) == TRUE) {
        $result = "pangram";
    }
}

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: The second version is wrong because it sets `$result` to `pangram` as soon as it finds a single matching letter. But it's only a pangram if **every** letter is found.

Comment: What do you mean by "predicates" in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version is incorrect because you can't determine that a sentence is a pangram based on checking just one character from the alphabet. So finding a matching character doesn't mean that it's a pangram. The only thing you can do is determine that a sentence is **not** a pangram when one of the letters in the alphabet does **not** exist in the test string. So you have to start with the assumption that it's a pangram, search for each letter, and when a search fails you conclude that it's not.

You can also stop looping once that happens -- one failure is enough to conclude that it's not a pangram.

```
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
    if (!strstr($line, $letter)) {
        $result = "not pangram";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I got it :) Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

very simple panagram checking code

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$stringData = str_split(strtolower($string));
$check = range('a', 'z');
$res = array_intersect($check, $stringData);
if(count($check) === count($res)) echo 'panagram';
else echo 'not panagram';
```

thats it

Comment: Works beautifully

Answer (score 0):

You have to use predicates, otherwise the result might change on each tick of the iteration:

```
$line = strtolower(trim("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog"));
$letters = str_split("thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog");
$result = true;
foreach ($letters as $value) {
    $result = $result && strstr($line, $value);
}

echo $result ? "pangram" : "not pangram";
```

With your code, if the first letter is found, the result will be `TRUE`, but if the next is not found, it will be `FALSE`, and, if the third is found, it will be `TRUE` again, and so on...